# foreach loops: How to update collection variable within loop?

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

Is there a way to change to behaviour that the collection variable for a loop cannot be updated from within its loop and use the new values in the next iteration?

For example:

```
$items = @(1,1,1,2)
$counter = 0

foreach ($item in $items) {
    $counter += 1
    Write-Host "Iteration:" $counter " | collection variable:" $items
    $item
    $items = $items | Where-Object {$_ -ne $item}
}

$counter
```

If you run this code the loop will execute for times.
However, since with the first iteration `$items` is changed from `1,1,1,2` to only contain `2`, the loop should only run once more.

I suspect this is because the collection variable `$items` is not updated in the foreach part.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Change `foreach ($item in $items)` to `foreach ($item in $items.Length)` and you will see the expected results.

Comment: The line `Write-Host "Iteration:" $counter " | collection variable:" $items` seems a little broken to me. Not related to your question, but you could simplify this, I'm sure

Comment: Thanks. .length works for my example but in my use case $items is an object. Specifying .lenth will cause $item alter its BaseType to System.Array. This effectively makes $item useless as it does not contain its original properties anymore.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  This feels like an X/Y problem.

Comment: @colonel_claypoo I think you're conflating observed behavior here, referencing `Length` does not change the type of `$items` (which would have to be the case for the `BaseType` to change). WRT to your question, you can't modify a collection while iterating over it. Please explain what you're trying to accomplish instead

Comment: I edited my initial post to contain more information.

Comment: @mklement0: Since the scope of my question was bigger than the question I wasked here, I created a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51421260/powershell-unable-to-filter-collection-of-objects-to-select-only-those-with-lat)

Comment: I appreciate it, @colonel_claypoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot use a `foreach` loop with a collection that is being modified in the loop body.**

Attempting to do so will actually result in an *error* (`Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.`)

The reason you're *not* seeing an error is that you're not actually modifying the original collection itself; you're assigning a *new* collection instance to the same *variable*, but that has no bearing on the original collection instance being enumerated.

You should **use a `while` loop instead**, in whose condition the `$items` variable reference is re-evaluated in every iteration:

```
$items = 1, 1, 1, 2
$counter = 0

while ($items) { # Loop as long as the collection has at last 1 item.
  $counter += 1
  Write-Host "Iteration: $counter | collection variable: $items"
  $item = $items[0] # access the 1st element
  $item # output it
  $items = $items | Where-Object {$_ -ne $item} # filter out all elements with the same val.
}
```

Now you get just 2 iterations:

```
Iteration: 1 | collection variable: 1 1 1 2
1
Iteration: 2 | collection variable: 2
2
```