# Unable to filter collection of objects to select only those with latest date

Tags: powershell, loops, object, foreach, filter

I have a collection of objects named `$items`:

[image]

I want to filter `$items` down to not contain duplicates according to the `FullName` property but have the unique object be the one with the latest date.

Since I couldn't figure out how to do that my solution approach was to first create a new object that only contains the duplicates in the form of the `FullName`property named `$duplicateItems`:

```
$arrDuplicates = @{}
$duplicateItems = foreach ($row in $restoreItems.FullName) {
  if ($arrDuplicates.ContainsKey($row) -and $arrDuplicates[$row] -lt 2) {
    $row
  }
  $arrDuplicates[$row] += 1
}
```

[image]

Then I tried to loop through `$items` and if the current `$item.FullName` exists in `$duplicateItems` select the object with the latest `DeletedDate`and restore it:

```
foreach ($item in $items) {
  if ($item.FullName -in $duplicateItems) {
    $filteredItem = $items | Where-Object {$_.FullName -eq $item.FullName} | Sort-Object DeletedDate | Select-Object -Last 1

    $filteredItem.Restore()
  }
  $items = items | Where-Object {$_.FullName -ne $item.FullName}
}
```

I thought if I used the `$items = items | Where-Object {$_.FullName -ne $item.FullName}` part the loop would only do `$filteredItem.Restore()` on the unique objects and not all of `$items`.

I'm sure there's a way easier solution to filter `$items` down to not contain duplicates according to the `FullName` property but have the unique object be the one with the latest date.

Comment: To go through each item in the hashtable you need to throw `.GetEnumerator()` onto it before filtering. So it would be `$items.GetEnumerator()`.

Comment: Have you tried `$items | Sort-Object DeletedDate -Descending | Select-Object Fullname -Unique`?

Comment: @Paxz: That works if all you're interested in is the full names, but it won't work for filtering the original list.

Comment: @DrewLean: That's true in general, but `$items` is not a hashtable here ("a collection of objects" - see the first screen shot; it is `$arrDuplicates` that is a hashtable, despite its name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-3.0) the files by their full name, then select the most recent file from each group:

```
$restoreItems | Group-Object FullName | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object DeletedDate | Select-Object -Last 1
}
```

This assumes that the timestamp is a `DateTime` object. Should it actually be a string you need to parse it to a `DateTime` object first, as LotPings pointed out in the comments, otherwise the sort order won't be correct.

Comment: Simple Title's as in the sample could occur in more than one folder, so I'd use FullName to group on, and sorting on `DeletedDate` works only if of type [datetime] - otherwise it would first have to be casted / ParseExact as [datetime]

Comment: @LotPings Yeah, I didn't read the question closely enough. Thanks for the heads up. As for the timestamps, I think it's pretty safe to assume that they're `DateTime` objects, but I added a note regardless.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing $items is a PowerShell Object and the blurred out information contains the same strings. You could try:

```
$items | Sort-Object -Property DeletedDate,Name -Unique
```

If the order is not right, try

```
$items | Sort-Object -Property DeletedDate,Name -Unique -Descending
```

Basically you just need to sort on two properties, and then select the unique values.

Comment: This won't work, because `-Unique` only weeds out objects for which _all_ of the specified properties' values match, whereas the input has duplicates by `FullName` (not `Name`), not by `DeletedDate`.